# How to add variables to api calls in blazemeter to load test GUI

Tags: testing, performance-testing, load-testing, ui-testing, blazemeter

I have been currently using jmeter for my load testing, this includes registering a user and using an authorization token and things of that nature, this includes using a json extractor/header extractor etc for each run as these variables would be dynamic and change.

This is working fine but im having issues when im trying to use the blazemeter gui tests. Im able to record the flow using the blazemeter extension but cant seem to find an option to load the jmeter script and combine it with the ui recording so i can run the GUI tests for multiple users.

I have already been able to add the jmx file to blazemeter and run it there but again i see no option to edit this within blazemeter or add it to any GUI tests?

All i want to do is assert that pages are loading within a certain duration but can seem to get this working with the apis and GUI.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There are different options of exporting a recorded script from the [BlazeMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/), it appears that you're looking for the `JMeter & Selenium combined (YAML)`

[image]

This `YAML`  will look like:

```
# Script generated by Blazemeter Chrome Extension

modules:
  nose:
    ignore-unknown-actions: true

execution:
- executor: selenium
  scenario: test-Selenium
  blazegrid: true

  capabilities: 
    browserName: chrome
  hold-for: 20m

- executor: jmeter
  scenario: test-Http
  concurrency: 20
  ramp-up: 1m
  hold-for: 19m

scenarios:
  test-Selenium:
    generate-flow-markers: true 
    headless: false
    timeout: 60s
    think-time: 0s
    requests:
    - label: Test
      actions:
      - go(chrome://newtab/)
      - go(http://example.com/)

  test-Http:
    headers:
      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: '1'
      User-Agent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'
      Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3'
    requests:
      - transaction: Test
        force-parent-sample: false
        do:
          - url: 'http://example.com/'
            method: GET
            label: 'http://example.com/'
            think-time: 0ms
            headers: {}
```

format is consumed by BlazeMeter's [Taurus tool](https://gettaurus.org/)

Check out:

- [Taurus Configuration Syntax](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ConfigSyntax/) - for generic information
- [JMeter Executor](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/) - for JMeter-specific settings
- [Selenium Executor](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Selenium/) - for Selenium-specific settings